# I'd like to iterate object using foreach statement

Tags: c#, extension-methods

There's a kind of list container(eg. MyList what I cannot modify) but declared only GetCount() and At() methods.

I'd like to use foreach statement for MyList, so I wrote extension method like bellow.

```
public static class MyListHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<MyListItemType> GetEnumerator(this MyList list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.GetCount(); ++i )
        {
            yield return list.At(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But if I code '**foreach (MyListItemType i in list)...**', compiler vomits 'MyList does not contain a piblic definition for GetEnumerator'.

I can invoke GetEnumerator() method directly and works okay.

What should I do more for that?

Comment: That is because you are trying to use an instance of a static class, try making the GetEnumerator method non-static (and inherit from IEnumerable)

Comment: It's an extension method, I assume because he doesn't have control of `MyList`.

Comment: Thanks Rawling, I cannot modify MyList class.

Comment: What confuses people, is that your static extension method class is called `MyList` as well. That's nor legal. The static class must have a name distinct from the non-static class you want to extend through an extension method.

Comment: Nielsen, u're right. it's my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't edit the code of the `MyList` (non-static) class directly, you probably have to make an extension method `ToIEnumerable` or similar. Maybe something like:

```
public static class MyListExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<MyListItemType> ToIEnumerable(this MyList list)
  {
    return new Wrapper(list)
  }

  private class Wrapper : IEnumerable<MyListItemType>
  {
    readonly MyList list;

    public Wrapper(MyList list)
    {
      this.list = list;
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyListItemType> GetEnumerator() 
    { 
      for (int i = 0; i < list.GetCount(); ++i )
      { 
        yield return list.At(i); 
      } 
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: But your solution still need to invoke ToIEnumerable() method in foreach statement explicitly. From my code, it's still valid if I invoke GetEnumerator() method explicitly also. Are there anything what I didn't understand completely?

Comment: @HongseokYoon Hmm, in your code you name the method `GetEnumerator`, but it actually retrurns an "enumerable", not an "enumerator". I didn't realize that. So you should rename your method to something with -able, like `GetEnumerable`, `AsEnumerable`, or `ToEnumerable`. After that, your code is better than mine! There is no way you can avoid having to call your extension method explicitly. (Not even with user-defined conversion operators; I tried.)

Answer (score 2):

Change `MyList` to implement the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) or `IEnumerable<T>` interface. This includes [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyList` need to implement interface `IEnumerable`

```
public class MyList:IEnumerable<MyListItemType>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyListItemType> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```